# Team explorer missing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, tfs

I followed this installation guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh301122.aspx

On some computers, all went well. But on some, the team explorer window is missing.

I can't find it even in: Window->Show view->Other. In fact there is no trace of TFS anywhere in eclipse (it does not appear at preferences under team). But it's listed in installed software.

All computers have Ubunto 12.04 LTS and eclipse 3.7.2 with eclipse cdt.

Comment: Your question helped me find Team Explorer altogether because it wasn't showing up for me. Going to `Window > Show View > Other...`, selecting Team Explorer and clicking OK got everything working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have Version Control (Team).
I recently installed Eclipse 4.20,
and I am thinking that the Team menu name was changed to Version Control (Team)
(Team -> Version Control (Team)).

Answer (score 0):

the solution apparently is to open eclipse with sudo and then start the installation.
some permission problem that wasn't notified by the installation.

Answer (score 0):

it may happen for permissions issue, you did not have enough permissions to the location where eclipse is installed so the installation of TEE failed.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue.  MSDN's site states: Team Explorer Everywhere is designed to be run as a non-root user on computers that are running Unix.

I was finally able to fix my issue by running the command below:
sudo chown -R user:user /usr/lib/eclipse/ /usr/share/eclipse/